# accepts_nested_attributes_for and Active Resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeresource

I'd like to use accepts_nested_attributes_for with Active Resource.  Is this possible?  I have been experimenting in console and passing in nested attributes works, however the nested models fail to create because the foreign_key is never set.

For example,

I have a user class that accepts_nested_attributes_for :credentials.  The JSON comes across as

```
"user" => { "name" => "Joe", "credentials" => ["username" => "joe", "password" => "password"]}
```

, so I copied that into console, but the credential validation fails since user_id is never set.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Works fine if I remove the validation on user_id, but I'd prefer to keep it despite having the validation on the database column.  What is the best approach to solve this?

Comment: I'm having the same issue - seems weird. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is your problem related with the JSON format of the object? If so, you could specify which attributes are exported to this format.